# Why do I get Object doesn't support mailitem property SenderEmailAddress?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to save an attachment from a specific sender that has a specific file extension in the attachment. I'm having trouble with the If part of my loop. I receive Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
    Sub GetAttachments()

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    i = 0

    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
               "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each Item In Inbox.Items

        If Item.SenderEmailAddress = "email@domain.com" Then
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
                If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = ".py" Then
                    FileName = "C:\Users\bill\Desktop\TEST\" & Atmt.FileName
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next Atmt
        End If
    Next Item

    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "I found " & i & " attached files." _
        & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the C:\Users\bill\Desktop\TEST folder." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Have a nice day.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail." , vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

GetAttachments_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub

GetAttachments_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume GetAttachments_exit
End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868262.aspx  If mpfInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then

Comment: Which `if`? `Item.Sender` or `if atmt`?

Comment: If `Item.Sender `

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*See this example*

```
    Filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = 'email@domain.com'"
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    ii = 0

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items.Item(i)

        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
            If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = ".py" Then
                FilePath = "C:\Temp\"
                FileName = Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FilePath & FileName
                ii = ii + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The Folder can contain various types of items. Some of them don't provide the [SenderEmailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868262(v=office.15).aspx) property. Try to check out the item class first (or MessageCLass).

Also you may get a security issue if you automate Outlook from another application. See [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52).

And don't interate over all items in the folder:

```
 For Each Item In Inbox.Items
   If Item.SenderEmailAddress = "email@domain.com" Then
```

You can use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class instead. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

Comment: I removed "Item." from "Item.SenderEmailAddress." to look like below:    ` For Each Item In Inbox.Items
   If SenderEmailAddress = "email@domain.com" Then` and that removed the error message but it did not find anything meeting that condition.

Comment: There is no need to remove the `Item` part. The property doesn't make any sense without the object.